# jQuery scrollTop() doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using this function to load Web Page in Chunks for reducing the page load time of the home page.

This is working fine in chrome and UC browser.Only the issue is coming in safari browser.

**This is my code :**

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())  //user scrolled to bottom of the page?
        {
}
```

when i am going to alert something inside the loop its also not working in **iphone**.
Guide me where i am doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i remember, that safari has a problem with jquerys window height.
try `window.innerHeight` instead.
So your code would look like this

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight == $(document).height()) {
    alert('bottom')
}
```

Comment: Mephiztopheles: nice..can i also check that scroll is just small above from the bottom.so that loader will call before scroll touch to bottom.

Comment: this would be like `$(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight >= $(document).height() - BUFFER`... i hope so :D didnt check it, but it should be like this  EDIT: you need `>=` because you cant be exact that value scrolling... so your function will trigger while your scrolling.. each scroll event... remember that

Comment: how did you use it? do you have a fiddle for me? then i can check and maybe help you :)